# In tableau, is there a way to hide/unhide a column of data, similar to excel? Not in data source, but in an actual worksheet?

Tags: tableau-api

I just have a bunch of dimensions in rows, so its just a table of information and I need to hide a column of data because its confidential, but I need the data there because it affects the layout of the rest of the table.

Comment: What do you mean "I need the data to be there"? -- if this is just a formatting issue, just create an empty field and replace the confidential field with a blank field. You cannot hide fields that have been placed on a shelf in the worksheet. Alternatively, you could create a calculated field to obscure the data, but again, I don't understand how you can "need the data" and yet not want it displayed. Are you using it in a calculation? if so, just put the calculation on the sheet.

Comment: Thanks for helping.  Im going to use a fake example. I have a list of people and where they live in a table format. The row I need to hide is a name. For example, the first row is a state column and the second a city column. If I don't put a name column in the third row, there will be a max of one row per city. However if I put in the name, then the number of rows reflects the actual number of people that live there, which I need. But I dont want the name to be shown.

Comment: sorry mixed up rows and columns.  I need to hide the column name, and not hide the state and city columns.

Comment: Hm. If you're trying to aggregate the data, just drag the "name" column to the shelf, right click it and select "Measure > Count" (Or "Count Distinct" if you have duplicates and want a distinct count) -- That should give you what you want. http://imgur.com/iWr5fkd

Comment: thanks for the help!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Right click on the field that you want to hide on the rows or columns shelf, and turn off show header